Graph Convolutional Networks Issue - Stuck at 0% Accuracy
I'm encountering a problem while training a Graph Convolutional Networks for a classification task, and I'm seeking assistance in troubleshooting it.
It iterates over each person's fingerprint extracted features data (100 people) and each sample of their fingerprint (8 samples per person).
An example of one of the data:
160,56,3,0.484832178465376
200,68,1,0.562318238080993
39,115,1,5.46065431073352
45,128,1,2.37348378271699
...
231,160,1,0.741114780012023
160,163,3,3.93182414892249
127,167,3,5.59876615916843
72,169,1,5.40727184206776


The following code is for create graph from the data, which I guess is the problem
import os
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import torch

path = "/kaggle/input/Datasets"
labels = []
adjacency_matrices = []

for person_id in range(1, 101):
    for sample_id in range(1, 9):
        csv_file = os.path.join(path, f"{person_id}_{sample_id}.csv")
        labels.append(person_id - 1)

        minutiae_points = []
        with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                x, y, minutiae_type, angle = line.strip().split(',')
                minutiae_points.append((int(x), int(y)))

        G = nx.Graph()
        G.add_nodes_from(minutiae_points)
        for i, (x1, y1) in enumerate(minutiae_points):
            for j, (x2, y2) in enumerate(minutiae_points):
                if i != j:
                    # Connect nodes based on their proximity
                    if np.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) < 50:
                        G.add_edge((x1, y1), (x2, y2))

        adjacency_matrix = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
        adjacency_matrices.append(torch.from_numpy(adjacency_matrix))

torch.save(adjacency_matrices, 'adjacency_matrices.pt')
torch.save(torch.tensor(labels), 'labels.pt')

Also, the continuation of the code is as follows:
import os
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.data import Data, DataLoader
from torch_geometric.nn import global_mean_pool
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from torch.utils.data import random_split

# Create a PyTorch Geometric dataset
fingerprint_dataset = []
num_features = 4  # Number of features for each csv
for i in range(len(adjacency_matrices)):
    edge_index = torch.nonzero(adjacency_matrices[i]).t().contiguous()
    x = torch.ones(edge_index.shape[1], num_features)  # Placeholder for node features
    data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index)
    fingerprint_dataset.append(data)

# Convert labels to a PyTorch Tensor
labels = torch.tensor(labels)

# Split the dataset into train and validation sets
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(fingerprint_dataset, [0.8, 0.2])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

# Define the GCN model
class FingerprintGCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels, num_classes):
        super(FingerprintGCN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.conv3 = GCNConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.lin = torch.nn.Linear(hidden_channels, num_classes)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index, batch = data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv3(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = global_mean_pool(x, batch)  # Average across nodes for each graph
        x = self.lin(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

# Initialize the model
num_classes = 100  # Number of persons
hidden_channels = 64
model = FingerprintGCN(num_features, hidden_channels, num_classes)

# Train the model
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
num_epochs = 100

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss = 0.0
    val_loss = 0.0
    train_acc = 0.0
    val_acc = 0.0

    # Training loop
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Forward pass
        output = model(batch)
        batch_labels = labels[batch_idx * train_loader.batch_size: (batch_idx + 1) * train_loader.batch_size]
        loss = criterion(output, batch_labels.long())

        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Compute training accuracy
        preds = output.argmax(dim=1)
        correct = (preds == batch_labels).sum().item()
        train_acc += correct / len(batch_labels)
        train_loss += loss.item()

    # Validation loop
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(val_loader):
            output = model(batch)
            batch_labels = labels[len(train_dataset) + batch_idx * val_loader.batch_size: len(train_dataset) + (batch_idx + 1) * val_loader.batch_size]
            loss = criterion(output, batch_labels.long())

            preds = output.argmax(dim=1)
            correct = (preds == batch_labels).sum().item()
            val_acc += correct / len(batch_labels)
            val_loss += loss.item()

    train_loss /= len(train_loader)
    val_loss /= len(val_loader)
    train_acc /= len(train_loader)
    val_acc /= len(val_loader)

    print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1}, Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Train Acc: {train_acc:.4f}, Val Acc: {val_acc:.4f}')

And finally the output is as follows
Epoch: 1, Train Loss: 4.6851, Val Loss: 4.7294, Train Acc: 0.0000, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 2, Train Loss: 4.5725, Val Loss: 4.8967, Train Acc: 0.0125, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 3, Train Loss: 4.5426, Val Loss: 5.0557, Train Acc: 0.0125, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 4, Train Loss: 4.5195, Val Loss: 5.2040, Train Acc: 0.0125, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 5, Train Loss: 4.5013, Val Loss: 5.3422, Train Acc: 0.0125, Val Acc: 0.0000
...
Epoch: 96, Train Loss: 4.3918, Val Loss: 9.0873, Train Acc: 0.0000, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 97, Train Loss: 4.3918, Val Loss: 9.1061, Train Acc: 0.0000, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 98, Train Loss: 4.3917, Val Loss: 9.1249, Train Acc: 0.0000, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 99, Train Loss: 4.3917, Val Loss: 9.1434, Train Acc: 0.0000, Val Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 100, Train Loss: 4.3916, Val Loss: 9.1619, Train Acc: 0.0000, Val Acc: 0.0000

Any suggestions, insights, or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Is that 8 samples of each finger? Or 8 samples, one of each finger? The second doesn't seem to me to provide enough data to generalise.

@JohnBayko All 8 samples belong to one finger of one person. For example, 8 samples of the right index finger of a person in different positions
